# Xamarin.Firebase.FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance returns NULL is Xamarin.Firebase.lid is used

Tags: firebase, xamarin, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to use Xamarin.Firebase.Dynamic.Links, but I get a NULL object whenever the Xamarin.Firebase.lid package is included in the project. However, I need to use other packages that rely on Xamarin.Firebase.lid, and so the solution isn't as simple as just NOT USING it.

The project is built against MONOANDROID 9.0, and all of the installed packages are the MOST UP-TO-DATE as of Sep 20, 2019.

The default FirebaseApp object instance is valid (non-null), so all of my account information in google-services.json seems to be working as expected.

I've proven that the issue disappears the moment I remove Xamarin.Firebase.lid from the packages, and it returns the moment I put this package back in.

I of course hadn't expected this failure to tie so closely to another package that is ALSO from Google and meant for use with Firebase.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? If so, how did you work around it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource. However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest solution attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: I got the same issue when upgrading to Xamarin.Firebase.Dynamic.Links version 71.1615.0. Looking for the solution too.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found that the ONLY way to fix this was to build against MONOANDROID 8.0. You can still TARGET Android 9.0 in your app, but all of your packages must be the older ones that work on MONOANDROID 8.0. If the package doesn't care, you can use the most recent of those.